# List of images in horizontal way using react.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to create a list of images having text just below it. All images in this list should be horizontal. I am using [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xGZ5/2/)
It is working fine without react.
But I want to do it in react as follows.

```
 a.subList.map((b) => (
                                    <figure id="figure">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <img src={b.imageUrl} />
                                                    <figcaption>{b.name}</figcaption>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>

                                    </figure>
                                ))
```

where a.subList is in this form

```
[{"imageUrl":"/acb","name":"cvb"},{"imageUrl":"/asdf","name":"cvbnm"}]
```

But using  react function  it is not showing in horizontal direction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's actually a styling issue, Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xGZ5/2/).
I chose [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to display the items horizontally, but you can choose something else.

```
 <div class="topContainer">

 </div>
```

and add the following css.

```
.topContainer{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Note about browser support: [It's actually safe to use it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). (97% support worldwide)